# Simplest way to add iAd/Admob into storyboard uitableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, admob, iad

When I first attempted to ad iAd in my first app, being a novice programmer, I painstakingly programmed in all of the x and y coordinates for everything with every possible layout for when the ad was showing and not showing... There is an easier way I know but what is it? If I have a uitableviewcontroller added via storyboard, and I want to add in an ad banner to the bottom of the screen, hence requiring the uitableview (not controller of course) to move up to accommodate the ad so that when scrolling to the bottom it won't get cut off, how would i do that the right and simplest way? I assume it would also be easier to add the banner programmatically but it doesn't matter i am looking for the simplest way.

Comment: Check my answer here for a complete implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685008/didfailtoreceiveadwitherror-not-working-for-ios-8-simulators/28708377#28708377