# How to layout the originalContentView, when canDisplayBannerAds is YES?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, iad, viewdidlayoutsubviews, candisplaybannerads

I've always wanted to develop word games, so I have purchased an app template - to learn from the source code.

After I have converted the template to ARC and to Storyboard I would like now to start using iAd in my app.

However when I put `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` to `viewDidLoad` of the main VC (where the game board with letters is displayed), then I notice that the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is only called once:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ... SKIPPED ...   
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        float min = MIN(self.viewWordTableContainer.frame.size.width,
                        self.viewWordTableContainer.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"XXX min=%f", min);
        self.constraintWordTableWidth.constant = min;
        self.constraintWordTableHeight.constant = min;
        [_wordTable viewDidLayoutSubviews];
        [self updateLabelWords];
    }
}
```

And as result the game board with letters is not resized properly and does not occupy the full width (here [fullscreen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku0LB.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

When I remove the line or change it to `NO`, then `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called several times (but surprisingly prints same value of `min=375`).

I understand that the main view of my VC is being stored away into [self.originalContentView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html) but why isn't the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` being called (as many times as necessary to layout the VC properly)?

I looked a lot in the debugger and also searched at SO (there are only 2 similar questions found) - please recommend me a workaround here.

How does the iAd solution even work? Shouldn't there be some method called by iAd to tell the original view to re-layout itself?

Comment: I'd suggest adding the iAd `AdBannerView` programmatically instead of using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES`. Using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES` doesn't allow for much control and has issues such as the one you're experiencing. Here's an answer showing how to implement both iAd and AdMob banner ads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685008/didfailtoreceiveadwitherror-not-working-for-ios-8-simulators/28708377#28708377