# iAd banner appears even if there is no ADBannerView on storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, iad

Here is my sample project that displays an iAd banner at the bottom of the view.

viewcontrollerOne.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface viewcontrollerOne : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@end
```

viewcontrollerOne.m

```
#import "viewcontrollerOne.h"

@implementation viewcontrollerOne

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{

}
-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError*)error
{

}

@end
```

iAd banner appears on the bottom of the screen even when I don't have an `ADBannerView`. Also, this banner appears on the **other** segued ViewControllers that have

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

and

```
<ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

and

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

Is this the proper way of implementing iAd banners? If so, why do all the other tutorials implement `ADBannerView` on storyboard, and use `[self.view addSubview: myAdBanner];`??

I am so confused...

Comment: What is the problem ?\

Comment: I want to know the proper way of using iAdBanners.. because the iAdbanner appeared this way covered my iAdbanner which i implemented using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` will automatically create an `ADBannerView` for you and display it on the bottom of your devices screen. If you'd like to implement an `ADBannerView` programmatically remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` and do so. [Here's a nice implementation of iAd and AdMob banner ads.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28708377/2108547)