# canDisplayBannerAds causing container view issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, iad, candisplaybannerads

I have added `canDisplayBannerAds` into my application and it's working great with one minor exception, it causes my container view to get clipped for some reason.

In the image below it shows a `UITextView` above a Container View.
Notice on the right side that the container view isn't fully rounded and is not appearing to be left-aligned with the text view.

The left hand side shows how it looks with `canDisplayBannerAds = NO`.
The right hand side shows how it looks with `canDisplayBannerAds = YES` .

[image: Example]

I've tried reproducing this in a simple project, but wasn't able to yet.  I have tried a suggestion I found elsewhere on SO to add `[self.originalContentView layoutSubviews];` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it didn't resolve the issue.

Before displaying the container view I am doing:

```
self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.containerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I removed the `masksToBounds` to see how it would look, and the left hand side still doesn't line up with the text view above it.

While I'm giving the textview left-align container view screenshot, when in landscape the container view is left-aligned to a label.  This also works fine when not displaying ads.  In addition, I am not referencing `self.view` anywhere in the code.

Is this just a bug with `canDisplayBannerAds` that I'm going to have to live with or is there something I can do about it?

Comment: `canDisplayBannerAds` is known to cause many issues. Try adding the `ADBannerView` programmatically. Here's an example of how to implement iAd and AdMob banners programmatically. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28708377/2108547

Comment: @DanielStorm I appreciate that post.  Ultimately I feel going that route would require a lot more work (handling rotation, adjusting size classes' constraints).  For now I resolved my situation by changing my leading to superview constraint from 0 to 4 while ads are displayed.