# Apple iAd working in Germany / Russia but not in Netherlands?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

[image]

In this screenshot you can see that my iAd advertisements have a very low fill rate. In Netherlands it's terrible. How is that possible? What can I do to improve it?
Is it even worth it because it looks like people don't like my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about the availability of iAd advertisements based on specific countries. Advertisers have to include the Netherlands in their list of targeted regions for iAd advertisements to appear in the Netherlands. Apparently the Netherlands isn't a very large market for iAd advertisers, the fill rate on one of my more popular applications is only 5% in the Netherlands. In addition, iAd is not supported globally. You can see a list of supported countries [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203102).

You should consider using another ad network, [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download?hl=en) is a popular one, when an iAd advertisement fails to be filled.

Comment: Okay thank you. I haven't look up AdMob yet , but I guess it won't be much more difficult to implement than iAd!

Comment: @Alexxxx AdMob has a tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?hl=en). Check some of my [AdMob answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2108547%20[admob]%20[iad]) also, specifically [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28708377/2108547).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do anything about the low fillrate.

Until now you don't have many users to get more accurate results you will have to wait.

A low fillrate for a certain country could mean that in this specific country there are not many advertisers active. At least regarding your app category.

Answer (score 0):

Netherlands somehow seems to be (almost) ignored whatsoever. AdMob might be a better choice although it's not paying as much as iAd does. Maybe include both SDK's and only load AdMob Ads when the phone is in Netherlands.

There are also people who wrote their own server scripts for ad distribution but this won't pay off unless you earn $100+ a day.

Lastly I need to say that 48 requests are not a reasonable amount, wait a week or two in order to let the metrics "stabilize"