# How to ads are displayed on iAds Banner in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

This is my first experience to integrate iAds. I used the following link

http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/

I implemented it perfectly. My application showing AddBannerView perfect but ads hides and showing not working. And I added adBannerView by using storyboard and connect its delegates and IBOutlets.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    if (! bannerIsVisible) {
        // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
        if (advertiseView.superview == nil) {
            [self.view addSubview:advertiseView];
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

    if (bannerIsVisible) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show the code you are using

Comment: That tutorial is quite dated. Check [here-Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) or [here-ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28708377/2108547) for a better implementation.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? The screenshot you included shows it actually working. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed is dated. The reason your `ADBannerView` is ending up in the middle of your view over a period of time is because of your `CGRectOffset` in your `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods. I'd guess its a problem with your `bannerIsVisible` `BOOL`.

Also, don't use the `beginAnimations:context:` method. From [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/commitAnimations):

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Here's an example of how to implement an `ADBannerView` programmatically. This example animates the `alpha` property of the `ADBannerView` to show or hide it. There's no need to set the `ADBannerView`'s frame either. It will know which device it is on and size itself appropriately. Just setting it's position is sufficient.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import iAd; // Import iAd

@interface ViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate> { // Include delegate
    ADBannerView *adView; // Create globally
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc]init]; // Alloc/init
    // Position
    adView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2,
                                self.view.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height / 2);
    adView.delegate = self; // Set delegate
    adView.alpha = 0.0; // Hide banner initially
    [self.view addSubview:adView]; // Add to view
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    // Delegate method called when the ADBannerView receives an ad
    NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");

    // Animate alpha change to show ADBannerView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        adView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Delegate method called when the ADBannerView fails
    // Can fail for multiple reasons so lets print why its failing in our NSLog
    NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", error);

    // Animate alpha change to hide ADBannerView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        adView.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```